# git fetch hanging on vscode and Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm not very well versed in git.

As the title says, I was having an issue with pulling code in Visual Studio Code using Source Control and GitLens, and I started messing around with SSH Keys. I guess I must have really messed up whatever was set up by default, because the issue went from Error: Failed to read Username to Error: git@github.com permission denied (publickey) to endlessly hanging when I try to fetch/pull/push in vscode, git bash, and Github Desktop.

I have exhausted all the advice I have found on this topic and I'm feeling very lost right now. Don't feel like reinstalling my OS but it feels like the only option. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: I should also mention that this began after switching from Atom to vscode.

Comment: Reinstalling OS would be too much overkill if you're doing it just for this purpose. You can simply delete your .ssh directory (`C:\Users\[WindowsUsername]\.ssh` in windows) to achieve the same effect. You can then follow [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) guide to set it up again. If you want to read more about SSH, [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys) is a nice place.

Comment: Deleting my .ssh directory is unfortunately something I've tried already to no avail :(

Comment: Could you post the commands that you're trying to run, and their outputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. I had to delete .ssh folder and set it back up, then I had to reset my remote origin.

I think that's what fixed it but as I said I'm not super well versed in git so it may have been something else I did accidentally lol